# Pass json object as parameter in c# method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json, ajax

I am getting the facebook data of the user using the facebook api as follow:

```
 function testAPI() {
            FB.api('/me?fields=id,name, birthday, picture.width(100).height(100), email', function (response) {
                if (response && !response.error)
                    //console.log(response);
                    buildProfile(response);
            })
        }
```

Now I want to pass the response json object to a method in c# as parameter. For doing that I am using the ajax as follows:

```
function buildProfile(user) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'callback.aspx/SaveData',
                data: JSON.stringify(user),
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                }
            });
        }
```

There is method with name SaveData in c#, I have setup a breakpoint on that method.

The url: 'callback.aspx/SaveData' defined above should I have called the callback.aspx page in which SaveData  method is present.
But somehow I am not able to redirect to the page callback.aspx and to method SaveData in c#.

```
 public void SaveData(List<string> strings)
 {
            string text = "";
 }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the details of that C# Controller Method you are referring to

Comment: "But somehow it is not working." What does that mean? An exeption? Unexpected behaviour?

Comment: If you don't post the not working method how can we help you?

Comment: I think you'd need your controller to accept a CLASS which matches the `user` object in terms of fields available, and *not* `Json.stringify` the data - just pass the `user` object as-is.  Then it should work.  At the moment MVC is probably trying to find an Action that expects a single `string` param and failing, so it's not calling the action on the controller.

Comment: Is your c# method marked as [WebMethod] ?

Comment: Please share your C# method. Are you using Webform or mvc or web service?

Comment: do some debugging so you can give us an actual description of the issue rather than "not working", which could mean 100 different things. We can't see all your code, we can't see your environment, we can't see what data you're sending or what the server is expecting. We need you to give us proper info. We can't read your screen, or your mind. It's like asking us to fix your car without looking at the engine. Do you understand how to use the Developer Tools in your browser to see what happens to the AJAX request and what response you get from the server? If not, now's a great time to learn.

Comment: I have edited my question and tried to defined the issue more clearly. Can you please check now?

Comment: Ok thanks. As the answer below notes, in WebForms you need to mark a method with the `[WebMethod]` attribute before it's accessible via an AJAX call. Also what does your `user` object look like actually? You accept a `List<string>` into the C# method but I really doubt this is likely to match with the object structure you're sending, so .NET will not be able to de-serialise the JSON correctly. If you show us the structure of `user`, we may be able to help you define a C# object which can map to the data.

Answer (score 1):

```
[WebMethod]
public void SaveData(List<string> strings)
{
      string text = "";
}
```

The specific method being called needs an attribute **WebMethod** to be defined to be called using an ajax, I don't see the attribute in your case.